# Multiple where statements in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Database structure sample:

Department Table
-DepartmentID

Facility Table
-Facility ID
-DepartmentID (FK)
-Block
-Level
-Name
-etc

I am trying to select from database from the EF using two where clause. I am not sure what went wrong at the where clause. I am stuck at it. Please help and advice. I have googled on the internet but cannot find the solution to it.

```
        string departmentID = "SIT";
        string block = "L";
        string level = "4";
        string name = "L.425";

        using (var db = new KioskContext())
        {
            var facilitys = from f in db.Facilitys
```

Where clause to select departmentID where equals to SIT and also where any block or level or name contains any alphabets. Please advice how should i write the statement with two where clause. Thank You!

```
                            where f.Department.DepartmentID == departmentID
                            && (f.Block.Contains("%" + block + "%") || f.Level.Contains("%" + level + "%")
                            || f.Name.Contains("%" + name + "%"))
```

Remaining of the query statement to select all the facilities

```
                            orderby f.FacilityID
                            select new
                            {
                                f.FacilityID,
                                f.DepartmentID,
                                f.Description,
                                f.Block,
                                f.Level,
                                f.Name,
                                f.OpenHours,
                                f.CloseHours,
                                f.MaxBkTime,
                                f.MaxBkUnits,
                                f.MinBkTime,
                                f.MinBkUnits
                            };
            foreach (var fac in facilitys)
            {
                FacObject facobject = new FacObject(fac.FacilityID, fac.DepartmentID, fac.Description, fac.Block, fac.Level,
                    fac.Name, fac.OpenHours, fac.CloseHours, fac.MaxBkTime, fac.MaxBkUnits, fac.MinBkTime, fac.MinBkUnits);
                sqlFacList.Add(facobject);
            }
        }
```

Comment: *I am not sure what went wrong at the where clause* - at least you should make this clearer. Your query syntax looks fine. So it's just the problem of business logic. I guess you should remove all `%`, you may mean you need something like `LIKE '%...%'` but if so the `Contains` will do that for you.

Comment: @Hopeless Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "%" from the various `Contains` clauses, they are SQL cruft you do not need.

```
where f.Department.DepartmentID == departmentID
     && (f.Block.Contains(block) 
     || f.Level.Contains(level)
     || f.Name.Contains(name ))
```

Remember LINQ is not just for SQL!

Comment: Thank You! @Richard Schneider